# Is it possible to us a csv file to connect one part of the algo to another

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv, lstm

I am trying to modify a triangular arbitrage crypto trading bot to include a predictive capability with a neural network. I've found some open source algorithms on GitHub, but I am having problem integrating them.

I've been trying to separate parts of the code into modules and using a continuously updated csv file to direct the data from the first half of the algorithm into the second, but it just isn't working.

I tried to create modules for different parts of the algorithm, but it didn't work:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from keras.models import Sequential
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

import time
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime
from pandas import Series
from matplotlib import cm

api_key = BinanceKey1['api_key']
api_secret = BinanceKey1['api_secret']

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)


import csv
import json 
from binance.client import Client

import csv
import json
from binance.client import Client

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

client = Client("", "")

klines1 = client.get_historical_klines("BNBBTC", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, 
                                      "1 day ago UTC")
csv.write(klines1)
# fetch 30 minute klines for the last month of 2017
klines2 = client.get_historical_klines("ETHBTC", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_30MINUTE, 
                                      "1 Dec, 2017", "1 Jan, 2018")
csv.write(klines2)
# fetch weekly klines since it listed
klines3 = client.get_historical_klines("NEOBTC", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1WEEK, 
                                      "1 Jan, 2017")
csv.write(klines3)


def load_data(klines, sequence_length):
    raw_data = pd.read_csv(klines, dtype=float).values
    for x in range(0, raw_data.shape[0]):
        for y in range(0, raw_data.shape[1]):
            if(raw_data[x][y] == 0):
                raw_data[x][y] = raw_data[x-1][y]

    data = raw_data.tolist()

    result = []
    for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
        result.append(data[index: index + sequence_length])

    d0 = np.array(result)
    dr = np.zeros_like(d0)
    dr[:, 1:, :] = d0[:, 1:, :] / d0[:, 0:1, :] - 1

    start = 2400
    end = int(dr.shape[0] + 1)
    unnormalized_bases = d0[start:end, 0:1, 20]

    split_line = round(0.9 * dr.shape[0])
    training_data = dr[:int(split_line), :]

    np.random.shuffle(training_data)

    X_train = training_data[:, :-1]
    Y_train = training_data[:, -1]
    Y_train = Y_train[:, 20]

    X_test = dr[int(split_line):, :-1]
    Y_test = dr[int(split_line):, 49, :]
    Y_test = Y_test[:, 20]

    Y_daybefore = dr[int(split_line):, 48, :]
    Y_daybefore = Y_daybefore[:, 20]

    sequence_length = sequence_length
    window_size = sequence_length - 1

    return X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, Y_daybefore, unnormalized_bases, window_size

def initialize_model(window_size, dropout_value, activation_function, loss_function, optimizer):

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(window_size, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(window_size, X_train.shape[-1]),))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_value))

    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM((window_size*2), return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_value))

    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(window_size, return_sequences=False)))

    model.add(Dense(units=1))

    model.add(Activation(activation_function))

    model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=optimizer)

    return model

def fit_model(model, X_train, Y_train, batch_num, num_epoch, val_split):

    start = time.time()

    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size= batch_num, nb_epoch=num_epoch, validation_split= val_split)

    training_time = int(math.floor(time.time() - start))
    return model, training_time

def test_model(model, X_test, Y_test, unnormalized_bases):


    y_predict = model.predict(X_test)

    real_y_test = np.zeros_like(Y_test)
    real_y_predict = np.zeros_like(y_predict)

    for i in range(Y_test.shape[0]):
        y = Y_test[i]
        predict = y_predict[i]
        real_y_test[i] = (y+1)*unnormalized_bases[i]
        real_y_predict[i] = (predict+1)*unnormalized_bases[i]

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title("Bitcoin Price Over Time")
    plt.plot(real_y_predict, color = 'green', label = 'Predicted Price')
    plt.plot(real_y_test, color = 'red', label = 'Real Price')
    ax.set_ylabel("Price (USD)")
    ax.set_xlabel("Time (Days)")
    ax.legend()

    return y_predict, real_y_test, real_y_predict, fig

def price_change(Y_daybefore, Y_test, y_predict):

    Y_daybefore = np.reshape(Y_daybefore, (-1, 1))
    Y_test = np.reshape(Y_test, (-1, 1))

    delta_predict = (y_predict - Y_daybefore) / (1+Y_daybefore)

    delta_real = (Y_test - Y_daybefore) / (1+Y_daybefore)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title("Percent Change in Bitcoin Price Per Day")
    plt.plot(delta_predict, color='green', label = 'Predicted Percent Change')
    plt.plot(delta_real, color='red', label = 'Real Percent Change')
    plt.ylabel("Percent Change")
    plt.xlabel("Time (Days)")
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()

    return Y_daybefore, Y_test, delta_predict, delta_real, fig

def binary_price(delta_predict, delta_real):

    delta_predict_1_0 = np.empty(delta_predict.shape)
    delta_real_1_0 = np.empty(delta_real.shape)

    for i in range(delta_predict.shape[0]):
        if delta_predict[i][0] > 0:
            delta_predict_1_0[i][0] = 1
        else:
            delta_predict_1_0[i][0] = 0
    for i in range(delta_real.shape[0]):
        if delta_real[i][0] > 0:
            delta_real_1_0[i][0] = 1
        else:
            delta_real_1_0[i][0] = 0    

    return delta_predict_1_0, delta_real_1_0

def find_positives_negatives(delta_predict_1_0, delta_real_1_0): 
    true_pos = 0
    false_pos = 0
    true_neg = 0
    false_neg = 0
    for i in range(delta_real_1_0.shape[0]):
        real = delta_real_1_0[i][0]
        predicted = delta_predict_1_0[i][0]
        if real == 1:
            if predicted == 1:
                true_pos += 1
            else:
                false_neg += 1
        elif real == 0:
            if predicted == 0:
                true_neg += 1
            else:
                false_pos += 1
    return true_pos, false_pos, true_neg, false_neg

def calculate_statistics(true_pos, false_pos, true_neg, false_neg, y_predict, Y_test):

    precision = float(true_pos) / (true_pos + false_pos)
    recall = float(true_pos) / (true_pos + false_neg)
    F1 = float(2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
    MSE = mean_squared_error(y_predict.flatten(), Y_test.flatten())

    return precision, recall, F1, MSE

X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, Y_daybefore, unnormalized_bases, window_size = load_data("Bitcoin Data.csv", 50)
 print (X_train.shape)
 print (Y_train.shape)
 print (X_test.shape)
 print (Y_test.shape)
 print (Y_daybefore.shape)
 print (unnormalized_bases.shape)
 print (window_size)

model = initialize_model(window_size, 0.2, 'linear', 'mse', 'adam')
print model.summary()

model, training_time = fit_model(model, X_train, Y_train, 1024, 100, .05)

print "Training time", training_time, "seconds"

y_predict, real_y_test, real_y_predict, fig1 = test_model(model, X_test, Y_test, unnormalized_bases)

plt.show(fig1)

Y_daybefore, Y_test, delta_predict, delta_real, fig2 = price_change(Y_daybefore, Y_test, y_predict)

plt.show(fig)


delta_predict_1_0, delta_real_1_0 = binary_price(delta_predict, delta_real)

print delta_predict_1_0.shape
print delta_real_1_0.shape

true_pos, false_pos, true_neg, false_neg = find_positives_negatives(delta_predict_1_0, delta_real_1_0)
print "True positives:", true_pos
print "False positives:", false_pos
print "True negatives:", true_neg
print "False negatives:", false_neg

precision, recall, F1, MSE = calculate_statistics(true_pos, false_pos, true_neg, false_neg, y_predict, Y_test)
print "Precision:", precision
print "Recall:", recall
print "F1 score:", F1
print "Mean Squared Error:", MSE


class Client(object):

    API_URL = 'https://api.binance.com/api'
    WITHDRAW_API_URL = 'https://api.binance.com/wapi'
    WEBSITE_URL = 'https://www.binance.com'
    PUBLIC_API_VERSION = 'v1'
    PRIVATE_API_VERSION = 'v3'
    WITHDRAW_API_VERSION = 'v3'

    SYMBOL_TYPE_SPOT = 'SPOT'

    ORDER_STATUS_NEW = 'NEW'
    ORDER_STATUS_PARTIALLY_FILLED = 'PARTIALLY_FILLED'
    ORDER_STATUS_FILLED = 'FILLED'
    ORDER_STATUS_CANCELED = 'CANCELED'
    ORDER_STATUS_PENDING_CANCEL = 'PENDING_CANCEL'
    ORDER_STATUS_REJECTED = 'REJECTED'
    ORDER_STATUS_EXPIRED = 'EXPIRED'

    KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE = '1m'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_3MINUTE = '3m'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_5MINUTE = '5m'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_15MINUTE = '15m'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_30MINUTE = '30m'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR = '1h'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_2HOUR = '2h'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_4HOUR = '4h'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_6HOUR = '6h'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_8HOUR = '8h'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_12HOUR = '12h'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY = '1d'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_3DAY = '3d'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_1WEEK = '1w'
    KLINE_INTERVAL_1MONTH = '1M'

    SIDE_BUY = 'BUY'
    SIDE_SELL = 'SELL'

    ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT = 'LIMIT'
    ORDER_TYPE_MARKET = 'MARKET'
    ORDER_TYPE_STOP_LOSS = 'STOP_LOSS'
    ORDER_TYPE_STOP_LOSS_LIMIT = 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT'
    ORDER_TYPE_TAKE_PROFIT = 'TAKE_PROFIT'
    ORDER_TYPE_TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT = 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'
    ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT_MAKER = 'LIMIT_MAKER'

    TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC = 'GTC'
    TIME_IN_FORCE_IOC = 'IOC'
    TIME_IN_FORCE_FOK = 'FOK'

    ORDER_RESP_TYPE_ACK = 'ACK'
    ORDER_RESP_TYPE_RESULT = 'RESULT'
    ORDER_RESP_TYPE_FULL = 'FULL'

    AGG_ID = 'a'
    AGG_PRICE = 'p'
    AGG_QUANTITY = 'q'
    AGG_FIRST_TRADE_ID = 'f'
    AGG_LAST_TRADE_ID = 'l'
    AGG_TIME = 'T'
    AGG_BUYER_MAKES = 'm'
    AGG_BEST_MATCH = 'M'

def run():
    initialize_arb()
    pass

def initialize_arb():

    welcome_message = "\n\n---------------------------------------------------------\n\n"
    welcome_message+= "Hello and Welcome to the Binance Arbitrage Crypto Trader Bot Python Script\nCreated 2018 by Joaquin Roibal (@BlockchainEng)"
    welcome_message+= "A quick 'run-through' will be performed to introduce you to the functionality of this bot\n"
    welcome_message+="To learn more visit medium.com/@BlockchainEng or watch introductory Youtube Videos"
    welcome_message+="\nCopyright 2018 by Joaquin Roibal\n"
    bot_start_time = str(datetime.now())
    welcome_message+= "\nBot Start Time: {}\n\n\n".format(bot_start_time)
    print(welcome_message)
    data_log_to_file(welcome_message)
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        status = client.get_system_status()
        list_of_symbols = ['ETHBTC', 'BNBETH', 'BNBBTC']
        list_of_symbols2 = ['ETHUSDT', 'BNBETH', 'BNBUSDT']
        list_of_symbols3 = ['BTCUSDT', 'BNBBTC', 'BNBUSDT']
        list_of_arb_sym = [list_of_symbols, list_of_symbols2, list_of_symbols3]
        tickers = client.get_orderbook_tickers()
        portfolio=[]
        with open('Portfolio.txt') as f1:
            read_data = f1.readlines()
            for line in read_data:
                load_portfolio = line       
        load_portfolio = list(load_portfolio[1:-1].split(','))
        i=0
        for val in load_portfolio:
            if i == 4:
                portfolio.append(str(datetime.now()))
                break
            portfolio.append(float(val))
            i+=1
        portf_msg = "Starting Portfolio: " + str(portfolio)
        print(portf_msg)
        portf_file_save(portfolio)
        data_log_to_file(portf_msg)
        while 1:
            calc_profit_list =[]
            for arb_market in list_of_arb_sym:
                calc_profit_list.append(arbitrage_bin(arb_market, tickers, portfolio, 1, 1))

            for profit1 in calc_profit_list:
                data_log_to_file(str(profit1))
            print(calc_profit_list)
            exp_profit = 0      
            m = n = 0       
            for exch_market in calc_profit_list:
                if exch_market[4]>exp_profit:
                    exp_profit = exch_market[4]
                    m = n
                n+=1
            profit_message = "\nMost Profitable Market: {} \nExpected Profit: {}%".format(list_of_arb_sym[m], exp_profit)
            print(profit_message)
            data_log_to_file(profit_message)
            time.sleep(5)
            arb_list_data = []
            arb_start_time = str(datetime.now())
            for i in range(0,5):
                arb_list_data.append(arbitrage_bin(list_of_arb_sym[m], tickers, portfolio, 1, 1, 'Yes'))
                time.sleep(30)
            arb_end_time = str(datetime.now())
            viz_arb_data(arb_list_data, list_of_arb_sym[m], arb_start_time, arb_end_time)
    except:
        print("\nFAILURE INITIALIZE\n")

def data_log_to_file(message):
    with open('CryptoTriArbBot_DataLog.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f.write(message)

def portf_file_save(portfolio):
    with open('Portfolio.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f.write('\n'+str(portfolio))

def arbitrage_bin(list_of_sym, tickers, portfolio, cycle_num=10, cycle_time=30, place_order='No'):
    arb_message = "Beginning Binance Arbitrage Function Data Collection - Running\n"
    print(arb_message)
    data_log_to_file(arb_message)
    time.sleep(2)
    fee_percentage = 0.05
    for i in range(0,1):
        """
            pairs = []
            for sym in symbols:
                for symbol in coins:
                    if symbol in sym:
                        pairs.append(sym)
            print(pairs)
            #From Coin 1 to Coin 2 - ETH/BTC - Bid
            #From Coin 2 to Coin 3 - ETH/LTC - Ask
            #From Coin 3 to Coin 1 - BTC/LTC - Bid
            arb_list = ['ETH/BTC'] #, 'ETH/LTC', 'BTC/LTC']
            #Find 'closed loop' of currency rate pairs
            j=0
            while 1:
                if j == 1:
                            final = arb_list[0][-3:]  + '/' + str(arb_list[1][-3:])
                            print(final)
                            #if final in symbols:
                            arb_list.append(final)
                            break
                for sym in symbols:
                    if sym in arb_list:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if j % 2 == 0:
                            if arb_list[j][0:3] == sym[0:3]:
                                if arb_list[j] == sym:
                                    pass
                                else:
                                    arb_list.append(sym)
                                    print(arb_list)
                                    j+=1
                                    break
                        if j % 2 == 1:
                            if arb_list[j][-3:] == sym[-3:]:
                                if arb_list[j] == sym:
                                    pass
                                else:
                                    arb_list.append(sym)
                                    print(arb_list)
                                    j+=1
                                    break
            """
        print("List of Arbitrage Symbols:", list_of_sym)
        list_exch_rate_list = []
        if 1:
            for k in range(0,cycle_num):
                i=0
                exch_rate_list = []
                data_collect_message1 = "Data Collection Cycle Number: "+str(k) +'\n'
                print(data_collect_message1)
                data_log_to_file(data_collect_message1)
                for sym in list_of_sym:
                    currency_pair = "Currency Pair: "+str(sym)+"\n"
                    print(currency_pair)
                    data_log_to_file(currency_pair)
                    if sym in list_of_sym:
                        """if i == 0:      #For first in triangle
                            depth = client.get_order_book(symbol=sym)
                            exch_rate_list.append(float(depth['bids'][0][0]))
                            print(depth['bids'][0][0])
                        """
                        if i % 2==0:
                            depth = client.get_order_book(symbol=sym)
                            inv1 = depth['asks'][0][0]
                            exch_rate_list.append(float(inv1))
                            Exch_rate1 = "Exchange Rate: {}".format(depth['asks'][0][0]) +'\n'
                            print(Exch_rate1)
                            data_log_to_file(Exch_rate1)
                        if i == 1:
                            depth = client.get_order_book(symbol=sym)
                            inv2 = round(1.0/float(depth['bids'][0][0]),6)
                            exch_rate_list.append(float(inv2))
                            Exch_rate2 = "Exchange Rate: {}".format(depth['bids'][0][0])+'\n'
                            print(Exch_rate2)
                            data_log_to_file(Exch_rate2)
                        i+=1
                    else:
                        exch_rate_list.append(0)
                exch_rate_list.append(datetime.now())
                rate1 = exch_rate_list[0]
                buy_price = "Buy: {}\n".format(rate1)
                print(buy_price)
                data_log_to_file(buy_price)
                rate2 = float(exch_rate_list[2])*float(exch_rate_list[1])
                sell_price = "Sell: {}\n".format(rate2)
                print(sell_price)
                data_log_to_file(sell_price)
                if float(rate1)<float(rate2):
                    arb_1_msg = "Arbitrage Possibility - "
                    arb_profit = round((float(rate2)-float(rate1))/float(rate2)*100,3)
                    arb_1_msg += "Potential Profit (Percentage): "+str(arb_profit) +'%\n'
                    print(arb_1_msg)
                    data_log_to_file(arb_1_msg)
                    exch_rate_list.append(arb_profit)
                    if place_order == 'Yes':
                        place_order_msg = "PLACING ORDER"
                        print(place_order_msg)
                        data_log_to_file(place_order_msg)
                        portfolio = tri_arb_paper(portfolio, list_of_sym, exch_rate_list)
                        portf_file_save(portfolio)
                else:
                    arb_2_msg = "No Arbitrage Possibility"
                    print(arb_2_msg)
                    data_log_to_file(arb_2_msg)
                    exch_rate_list.append(0)
                exch_msg = "Exchange Rate List: " +str(exch_rate_list)+'\n'
                print(exch_msg)
                data_log_to_file(exch_msg)
                time.sleep(cycle_time)
            print('\nARBITRAGE FUNCTIONALITY SUCCESSFUL - Data of Exchange Rates Collected\n')
    return exch_rate_list

def tri_arb_paper(portfolio1, sym_list, list_exch_rates):
    tri_arb_paper_msg = "\nSTARTING TRI ARB PAPER TRADING FUNCTION\n"
    print(tri_arb_paper_msg)
    time.sleep(10)
    data_log_to_file(tri_arb_paper_msg)
    if sym_list[0][-3:]=='BTC':
        portf_pos = 0
    elif sym_list[0][-3:]=='ETH':
        portf_pos = 1
    elif sym_list[0][-3:]=='SDT':
        portf_pos = 2
    elif sym_list[0][-3:]=='BNB':
        portf_pos = 3
    start_amount = float(portfolio1[portf_pos])
    amt_coin2 = start_amount / float(list_exch_rates[0])
    amt_coin3 = amt_coin2 * float(list_exch_rates[1])
    final_amount = amt_coin3 * float(list_exch_rates[2])
    tri_arb_paper_msg = "Starting Amount: "+str(sym_list[0][-3:])+" "+str(start_amount)+'\n'
    tri_arb_paper_msg += "Amount Coin 2: "+str(sym_list[0][0:3])+" "+str(amt_coin2)+'\n'
    tri_arb_paper_msg += "Amount Coin 3: "+str(sym_list[2][0:3])+" "+str(amt_coin3) +'\n'
    tri_arb_paper_msg += "Final Amount: "+str(sym_list[0][-3:])+" "+str(final_amount)+'\n'
    print(tri_arb_paper_msg)
    data_log_to_file(tri_arb_paper_msg)
    portfolio1[portf_pos] = final_amount
    portfolio1[-1] = str(datetime.now())
    return portfolio1

def viz_arb_data(list_exch_rate_list, arb_market, start_time, end_time):
    viz_msg = "RUNNING ARBITRAGE VISUALIZATION FUNCTIONALITY"
    print(viz_msg)
    data_log_to_file(viz_msg)
    rateA = []      
    rateB = []      
    rateB_fee = []  
    price1 = []     
    price2 = []
    time_list = []
    profit_list = []
    for rate in list_exch_rate_list:
        rateA.append(rate[0])
        rateB1 = round(float(rate[1])*float(rate[2]),6)
        rateB.append(rateB1)
        price1.append(rate[1])
        price2.append(rate[2])
        profit_list.append(rate[4])
        time_list.append(rate[3])
    viz_msg2 = "Rate A: {} \n Rate B: {} \n Projected Profit (%): {} ".format(rateA, rateB, profit_list) #rateB_fee))
    print(viz_msg2)
    data_log_to_file(viz_msg2)

    fig, host = plt.subplots()
    fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

    par1 = host.twinx()
    par2 = host.twinx()
    par2.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.2))
    make_patch_spines_invisible(par2)
    par2.spines["right"].set_visible(True)
    p1, = host.plot(time_list, rateA, "k", label = "{}".format(arb_market[0]))
    p1, = host.plot(time_list, rateB, "k+", label = "{} * {}".format(arb_market[1], arb_market[2]))
    p2, = par1.plot(time_list, price1, "b-", label="Price - {}".format(arb_market[1]))
    p3, = par2.plot(time_list, price2, "g-", label="Price - {}".format(arb_market[2]))
    host.set_xlabel("Time")
    host.set(title='Triangular Arbitrage - Exchange: {}\nStart Time: {}\n End Time: {}\n'
                   'Copyright (c) 2018 @BlockchainEng'.format('Binance', start_time, end_time))
    host.set_ylabel("Exchange Rate")
    par1.set_ylabel("Price - {}".format(arb_market[1]))
    par2.set_ylabel("Price - {}".format(arb_market[2]))
    host.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
    tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
    host.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), **tkw)
    par1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p2.get_color(), **tkw)
    par2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p3.get_color(), **tkw)
    host.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

    lines = [p1, p2, p3]
    host.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines])
    fname = "Binance_Test.png"
    plt.savefig(fname)
    """, dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',
        orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
        transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1,
        frameon=None)"""
    print_figure_message = "Data Collected Figure Printed & Saved - " + str(fname)
    print(print_figure_message)
    data_log_to_file(print_figure_message)

def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)
    """

def market_depth(sym, num_entries=20):
    #Get market depth
    #Retrieve and format market depth (order book) including time-stamp
    i=0     #Used as a counter for number of entries
    #print("Order Book: ", convert_time_binance(client.get_server_time()))
    depth = client.get_order_book(symbol=sym)
    print(depth)
    print(depth['asks'][0])
    ask_tot=0.0
    ask_price =[]
    ask_quantity = []
    bid_price = []
    bid_quantity = []
    bid_tot = 0.0
    place_order_ask_price = 0
    place_order_bid_price = 0
    max_order_ask = 0
    max_order_bid = 0
    print("\n", sym, "\nDepth     ASKS:\n")
    print("Price     Amount")
    for ask in depth['asks']:
        if i<num_entries:
            if float(ask[1])>float(max_order_ask):
                #Determine Price to place ask order based on highest volume
                max_order_ask=ask[1]
                place_order_ask_price=round(float(ask[0]),5)-0.0001
            #ask_list.append([ask[0], ask[1]])
            ask_price.append(float(ask[0]))
            ask_tot+=float(ask[1])
            ask_quantity.append(ask_tot)
            #print(ask)
            i+=1
    j=0     #Secondary Counter for Bids
    print("\n", sym, "\nDepth     BIDS:\n")
    print("Price     Amount")
    for bid in depth['bids']:
        if j<num_entries:
            if float(bid[1])>float(max_order_bid):
                #Determine Price to place ask order based on highest volume
                max_order_bid=bid[1]
                place_order_bid_price=round(float(bid[0]),5)+0.0001
            bid_price.append(float(bid[0]))
            bid_tot += float(bid[1])
            bid_quantity.append(bid_tot)
            #print(bid)
            j+=1
    return ask_price, ask_quantity, bid_price, bid_quantity, place_order_ask_price, place_order_bid_price
    #Plot Data
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Ideally, the code is supposed to find arbitrage opportunities in predicted price changes and execute orders accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid your code snippet might be a little too long. Could you shorten it so we can see the important parts only?

Comment: First of all the question is too long: I cut off part of the text. The code should be reduced too but the questioner should do it. 

Python is not a compilative language

Comment: Take a loot at the  [mcve]. Your code seems too difficult and time-consuming to be debugged by other programmers. Try to reproduce your problem in a similar shorter program and modify your question accordingly.